# How to find which field is giving data type error in QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query report for user but have some error message display:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

only one message.

How to find which field is giving  data type error in query? Anyone can give advice? Many thanks!

Comment: It helps to also show us the query, and maybe some sample data as well.

Comment: The query is our company . The query working in UAT site but launch to production is not working.

Comment: By field I guess you mean column? `where try_convert(MyColumn,bigint) is null`?

Comment: @Dale K  yesyes!

Comment: you can try to obfuscate column names and share the query and it will be helpful to see the issue

Comment: _launch to production is not working_ That is a valuable lesson - your environments are not exactly the same. Fix that!!

Comment: thanks all for the support me!!!!!!! i love you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided data, it looks like you have NVARCHAR datatype, which is not implicitly convertable to Bigint

> SELECT CAST(N'287888' AS BIGINT) -- Success
> SELECT CAST(N'ABC123' AS BIGINT) -- Failure

See which column is failing and accordingly fix it.

You can either only load the proper values:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TRY_CAST(ErrorField AS BIGINT) IS NOT NULL
```

Or, You can load them as NULL(provided the target column allows NULL)

```sql
SELECT TRY_CAST(ErrorField AS BIGINT) FROM Table
```